# Apply a dynamic group value in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

How could I give a group value to the stream binders dynamically, for flexibility while using Spring Cloud Stream. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot configuration properties can use property placeholder to be based on other properties or environment variables.

So, the mentioned `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<bindingName>.group` can be something like this:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.MY_INPUT_QUEUE.group=${my.envvar}
```

This way you can rely on something what is relevant to the environment where your service has started.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.property-placeholders